# Fetch, build and link of SDL2 fails with undefined `floor` references using CMake

Tags: cmake, sdl-2, libm

I am having the error below when I link my program with SDL2

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../_deps/sdl2_content-build/libSDL2d.a(SDL_stdlib.c.o): in function `SDL_floor_REAL':
/home/user/myprogram/cmake-build-debug/_deps/sdl2_content-src/src/stdlib/SDL_stdlib.c:247: undefined reference to `floor'
```

I made a FetchSDL2.cmake file that is included that should theoretically get it and build and use it:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    sdl2_content
    URL https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.12.tar.gz
    URL_HASH MD5=783b6f2df8ff02b19bb5ce492b99c8ff
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(sdl2_content)
if(NOT sdl2_content_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(sdl2_content)
  if(ANDROID)
      set(SDL_SHARED ON CACHE BOOL "shared")
      set(SDL_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "static")
      add_subdirectory(${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR} ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
      add_library(SDL2::SDL2 ALIAS SDL2)
      add_library(SDL2::SDL2main ALIAS SDL2main)
  elseif(WIN32 OR LINUX OR MACOS)
      set(SDL_SHARED OFF CACHE BOOL "no shared")
      set(SDL_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "static")
      set(SDL_STATIC_PIC ON CACHE BOOL "Static version of the library should be built with Position Independent Code")
      set(SDL_SHARED OFF)
      set(SDL_STATIC ON)
      set(SDL_STATIC_PIC ON)
      set(FORCE_STATIC_VCRT ON CACHE BOOL "static windows static vcrc")
      add_subdirectory(${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR} ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
      add_library(SDL2::SDL2 ALIAS SDL2-static)
      add_library(SDL2::SDL2main ALIAS SDL2main)
  endif()

  if(NOT EXISTS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2")
      execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2)
  endif()

  find_package(LibM)
  set(SDL2_INCLUDE_HINTS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/" "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2/")
  set(SDL2_LIB_HINTS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/")
  find_package(SDL2)
  list(APPEND SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2/")
  list(APPEND SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/")
  list(APPEND SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${LIBM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  list(APPEND SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/")
  list(APPEND SDL2_LIBRARIES SDL2::SDL2)
  list(APPEND SDL2_LIBRARIES "${LIBM_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
```

But I keep get the error above. I do have LibM, and every other math function links correctly. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 .

Can you help fix this so it fetches SDL2 correctly? The reason I am not installing it is this script will be used by CMake in some platforms that have no package managers.

Comment: Knowing only the code shown we can only **guess** what is wrong: Your code contains neither creation of your program (`add_executable`), nor its linkage and nor "Find" scripts for packages like `LibM` (this script is not shipped with CMake). I would suggest to obtain exact command line used for linking (`make VERBOSE=1`) and verify, that this line has `-lm` **after any** instance of SDL library.

Comment: I can remove the LibM code and it will still fail with the same complaint. It's just floor, all other math functions are OK. If I instead fetch a local version where I modify to have custom floor not on math.h it builds and works ok, but I need to be able to use the SDL2 original code.

Comment: My previous comment doesn't mean that you do something wrong. The meaning of my previous comment is that information provided by you is **insufficient** for us being able to help you.

Comment: I am out of the computer right now, so I can't use make VERBOSE right now to check - I will come back later.  My full source is here: https://github.com/ericoporto/ags/tree/529976d25483554a995e76188b440e465716a722 . For now I am using installed sdl2 when available for development. The curious thing for me is ONLY the floor function erroring which is why I asked here, I wanted to see if this was known error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. Turns out SDL2 has two headers with the same name `SDL_config.h`. The one you want to include is the generated by CMake and not the one that comes with the library.

Below is my CMake file that correctly removes and installs the right headers. Tested with SDL 2.0.12.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    sdl2_content
    URL https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.12.tar.gz
    URL_HASH MD5=783b6f2df8ff02b19bb5ce492b99c8ff
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(sdl2_content)
if(NOT sdl2_content_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(sdl2_content)
    if(ANDROID)
        set(SDL_SHARED ON CACHE BOOL "shared")
        set(SDL_STATIC OFF CACHE BOOL "static")
        add_subdirectory(${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR} ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
        add_library(SDL2::SDL2 ALIAS SDL2)
    elseif(WIN32 OR LINUX OR MACOS)
        set(SDL_SHARED OFF CACHE BOOL "shared")
        set(SDL_STATIC ON CACHE BOOL "static")
        set(SDL_STATIC_PIC ON CACHE BOOL "Static version of the library should be built with Position Independent Code")
        set(SDL_SHARED OFF)
        set(SDL_STATIC ON)
        set(SDL_STATIC_PIC ON)
        if(LINUX)
            set(SNDIO_SHARED ON CACHE BOOL "static")
            set(SNDIO_SHARED ON)
        endif()
        set(FORCE_STATIC_VCRT ON CACHE BOOL "static windows static vcrc")
        add_subdirectory(${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR} ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
        add_library(SDL2::SDL2 ALIAS SDL2-static)
    endif()
    add_library(SDL2::SDL2main ALIAS SDL2main)

    file(GLOB INCLUDE_FILES ${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h)
    file(GLOB BIN_INCLUDE_FILES ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/*.h)
    foreach(_FNAME ${BIN_INCLUDE_FILES})
        get_filename_component(_INCNAME ${_FNAME} NAME)
        list(REMOVE_ITEM INCLUDE_FILES ${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${_INCNAME})
    endforeach()
    list(APPEND INCLUDE_FILES ${BIN_INCLUDE_FILES})

    if(NOT EXISTS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2")
        file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2")
        file(COPY ${INCLUDE_FILES}  DESTINATION "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2")
    endif()
    include_directories("${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include")

    if(EXISTS "${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR}/android-project")
        file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${sdl2_content_SOURCE_DIR}/android-project")
    endif()

    file(COPY CMake/Extra/sdl2-config.cmake DESTINATION ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR})
    set(SDL2_DIR ${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR})
    list(APPEND SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/SDL2/")
    list(APPEND SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/include/")
    list(APPEND SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS "${sdl2_content_BINARY_DIR}/")
    list(APPEND SDL2_LIBRARIES SDL2::SDL2)
    list(APPEND SDL2_LIBRARIES SDL2::SDL2main)
endif()

message("SDL2_LIBRARIES: ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}")
message("SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

*Note: I additionally removed the Android project files since they were conflicting when I was running SDL2 on Android, but this doesn't matter for this question.*